# Выбор по двум параметрам

Tags: sql

Можно ли как-то объединить в один запрос 2 коротких, считающих количество записей в таблице по двум разным параметрам? Запросы такие:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE param = ...
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE param = ... AND date = ...
```

То есть, получается, что второй запрос содержит в себе первый с неким дополнением. Но на выходе нужны оба значения.

Comment: оба значение в одной строке или в 2 строках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS column1, SUM(IF(`date` = ..., 1, 0)) AS column2
FROM `table` 
WHERE `param` = ...
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa91b/1

В первом столбце количество строк с нужным параметром, во втором - с нужной датой и параметром.

**UPD**

Хотя меня смущают ваши взаимно исключаемые пояснения

> по двум разным параметрам

и

> что второй запрос содержит в себе первый с неким дополнением.

Comment: Ваш вариант явно лучше на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Ruslan, надо тестировать, что эффективней.

Comment: первый вариант сработает только если БД догадается оптимизировать UNION. Я конечно давно не обращался к изменениям, но изначально UNION выполнялся просто как отдельный запрос и значит вариант выше ничем особым не отличается от простых двух запросов. Возможно какие-то изменения и были сделаны позже и моя информация устарела, но у меня нет подобной информации.

Comment: "первый вариант сработает только если БД догадается оптимизировать UNION" , а причем здесь оптимизация ? вопрос вроде бы  как объединить результат 2 запросов в 1 или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @Xramovnic С одной стороны вы правы и вопрос не уточняет конечной цели, с другой эта цель читается в подтексте (на мой взгляд и я его не хочу навязывать) и предполагает поиск оптимального решения. Возможно я не прав именно поэтому я не голосовал против вашего варианта, а выбрал этот с моей точки зрения.

Answer (score 4):

можно реализовать через union

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE param = ...
union 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE param = ... AND date = ...
```

если нужно все значения с дубликатами union all

или  еще вариант через join но union по моему более "красивый"

```
SELECT aid,bid
 from  (select count(id) as aid from table where .... )a
 left join (select count(id) as bid from table where .... ) b on 1=1
```

Comment: union может и более красивый, но менее правильный. если оба запроса вернут одинаковый count, записи при использовании union [схлопнутся](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/17804) и будет одна запись в результате. так что union all. второй вариант не менее скучен, чем вопрос... но хоть верный.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when param = ... then 1 else 0 end) a,
sum(case when param = ... and date = then 1 else 0 end)
from ...
```